# Using helper functions in Elixir macros

Tags: macros, metaprogramming, elixir

Continuing the [Binding and unquote fragments](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html) example from the Elixir documentation...

We have a macro that defines functions based on a Keyword list.

```
defmodule MacroFun do

  defmacro defkv(kv) do
    quote bind_quoted: [kv: kv] do
      Enum.each kv, fn {k, v} ->
        def unquote(k)(), do: unquote(v)
      end
    end
  end

end

defmodule Runner do
  require MacroFun

  kv = [foo: 1, bar: 2]
  MacroFun.defkv(kv)

end

Runner.foo
```

Now let's move the body of the macro to a helper function.

```
  defmacro defkv(kv) do
    _defkv(kv)
  end

  defp _defkv(kv) do
    quote bind_quoted: [kv: kv] do
      Enum.each kv, fn {k, v} ->
        def unquote(k)(), do: unquote(v)
      end
    end
  end
```

Great, everything still works.  But now what if we want to make another macro that modifies `kv` before passing it to the private helper function:

```
  defmacro def_modified_kv(kv) do
    quote bind_quoted: [kv: kv] do
      modified_kv = Enum.map kv, fn {k, v} -> {k, v + 1} end
      _defkv(modified_kv)
    end
  end
```

That doesn't work.  Elixir says `_devkv` is not defined.  We can fix by using a fully qualified function name:

```
  defmacro def_modified_kv(kv) do
    quote bind_quoted: [kv: kv] do
      modified_kv = Enum.map kv, fn {k, v} -> {k, v + 1} end
      MacroFun._defkv(modified_kv)
    end
  end
```

But then Elixir complains that `MacroFun._defkv` is private.  So we change it to public, but it *still* doesn't work because the helper method `_devkv` returns quoted code to our macro `def_modified_kv` which itself is quoted!

So we can fix that by eval'ing the code returned by the helper function (final code):

```
defmodule MacroFun do

  defmacro defkv(kv) do
    _defkv(kv)
  end

  defmacro def_modified_kv(kv) do
    quote bind_quoted: [kv: kv] do
      modified_kv = Enum.map kv, fn {k, v} -> {k, v + 1} end
      MacroFun._defkv(modified_kv) |> Code.eval_quoted([], __ENV__) |> elem(0)
    end
  end

  def _defkv(kv) do
    quote bind_quoted: [kv: kv] do
      Enum.each kv, fn {k, v} ->
        def unquote(k)(), do: unquote(v)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

1. Why did I have to change to calling the helper function by its fully qualified name?
2. Why did I have to change the helper function to be public (from private)?
3. Is there a better way to do this besides calling `Code.eval_quoted`?

I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to import the module.
2. When you import a module, you can only import public methods.
3. Macros are a compile time feature, they write actually write code (or AST) in the module. So, the context of the macro when it's expanded, is where you're calling/using it. Thus, if you use a macro (not defined in) `SomeOtherModule` that's the context of macro expansion. In `SomeOtherModule` you would need to `import MacroFun` to call its functions locally.

The code below works in Elixir >= 1.2.0

E.g.

```
defmodule MacroFun do

  defmacro defkv(kv) do
    _defkv(kv)
  end

  defp _defkv(kv) do
    quote bind_quoted: [kv: kv] do
      Enum.each kv, fn {k, v} ->
        def unquote(k)(), do: unquote(v)
      end
    end
  end

  defmacro def_modified_kv(kv) do
    quote bind_quoted: [kv: kv] do
      modified_kv = Enum.map kv, fn {k, v} -> {k, v + 1} end
      defkv(modified_kv)
    end
  end
end

defmodule Runner do
  import MacroFun

  kv = [foo: 1, bar: 2]
  def_modified_kv(kv)

end
```

Hope this answers your questions! Good luck.

Updated a couple times because macros are a little confusing!

Comment: So basically, the twos thing you do differently are *1)* you call the **public** `defkv` **macro** instead of the **private** `_defkv` **function**, *2)* you use **`import`** instead of `require`

Comment: Isn't it `require`, and not `import`, that's supposed to be called when we want to use the macros defined by another module? Why does `import` work in this case?

Comment: `require` is just a gotcha of modules with macros-- it's really just importing the module. `import` accomplishes the same thing, inspect the AST.

Answer (score 0):

1) By using `require`, you've told the compiler to compile and make available `MacroFun`s **public** macros and functions. Note that the functions would be available anyway though:

> Notice that usually modules should not be required before usage, the only
>   exception is if you want to use the macros from a module.

2) They are available through their FQN

3) Here's my take on it:

```
defmodule MicroFun do
  defmacro defkv(kv) do
    _defkv(kv)
  end

  defp _defkv(kv) do
    quote bind_quoted: [kv: kv] do
      Enum.each kv, fn {k,v} ->
        def unquote(k)(), do: unquote(v)
      end
    end
  end

  defmacro modifier(kv) do
    quote bind_quoted: [kv: kv] do
      Enum.map kv, fn {k,v} -> {k, v+1} end
    end
  end
end

defmodule Runner do
  require MicroFun

  [foo: 1, bar: 2]
  |> MicroFun.modifier
  |> MicroFun.defkv
end
```

The idea is that you don't need to nest macros/functions when you can just pipe them.